# Drag & Drop between Listview and RichTextBox doesn't work

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I have a windows form containing a Listview and a RichTextBox. I want to write Listview items value in RichTextBox using drag & drop. To do it, I wrote this code in Listview `ItemDrag()` event handler:

```
listView1.DoDragDrop(((ListViewItem)e.Item).Text, DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

In RichTextBox `DragEnter()` event handler, I wrote this code:

```
private void  richTextBox1_DragEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
{
    string data = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
    richTextBox1.Text = data;
}
```

When I drag a Listview item, ItemDrag event is invoked, but when I release mouse-button in textbox nothing happens. DragEnter and DragDop event aren't Invoked. Otherwise during drag & drop operation, mouse cursor doesn't show "copy icon".

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the `AllowDrop` Property to true on the target control?
You can do that in the Properties Window in VS

Comment: Perfect! It works! AllowDrop property is available by code and not in porperty pane. I don't know why. Thanks!